# Teleop control not working in Turtlebot simulator

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I following this tutorial,

http://
wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world
but teleop not working.

I'm using Gazebo 2.1.0 and ROS Hydro.

I used $roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch AND $roslaunch kobuki_keyop keyop.launch and there isn't error message. I have no idea why it doesn't work.
I'm not sure if they've started on different servers and are unable to communicate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107981/teleop-control-not-working-in-turtlebot-simulator/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2013-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-07**:
Please say what you are doing and what you expect to happen and what is happening so that we can reproduce the problem. Otherwise we cannot help you.

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2013-12-07**:
The problem is that following step by step tutorial I should drive the turtlebot by Keyboard. When I run Roslaunch nothing happens, I can't move turtlebot in Gazebo. It seems that Gazebo and turtlebot_teleop doesn't speak.

I installed everything as the tutorial says.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-07**:
Are you keeping focus in the teleop window?

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2013-12-07**:
Yes, but nothing happens. Teleop indicates change of speed but Turtlebot is stopped.

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2013-12-08**:
I'm getting the same problem, just following the teleop tutorial that Prima89 mentioned. I can see velocity commands are being published to the /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop topic, but the Turtlebot doesn't respond. Perhaps it's a problem with cmd_vel_mux then? Or mobile_base_nodelet_manager?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-12-08**:
The official ros release gazebo version is 1.9.2.

Using gazebo 2.1.0 would be the problem. Can you try with gazebo version 1.9.2?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-12-08**:
Useful another answer

http://answers.ros.org/question/99276/turtlebot2-does-not-move-in-gazebo/

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2013-12-08**:
Works in Gazebo 1.9.1. Thanks very much jihoonl and tfoote!

@Prima89: refer to this post for how to downgrade from Gazebo 2.1.0 to 1.9.1: http://answers.ros.org/question/101976/ros-hydro-desktop-full-installs-gazebo-current-instead-of-gazebo/

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2013-12-08**:
Works!!! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Opps, looks like I accidentally upgraded Gazebo from 1.9.2 to 2.1.0 in the latest package update. I will try again with 1.9.2.

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0